# Can a data pipeline be in Access or SAS procedure? Definition

Tags: ms-access, sas, pipeline

Data definition assistance:

So I was talking to some data analyst acquaintances of mine the other day and described my setup:

1. I have set up mechanisms where large invoices that are received every month are imported into an Access database, processed by about 10 procedures, then loaded into a SQL database for permanent storage where people run queries off of for long term stats, CPRAs, short term reports, etc.
2. I also have long SAS procedures that harvest information from a very large Oracle database, process them, then upload them to a different SQL database for demographics and statistical mapping.

One of them said they were rudimentary "data pipelines" (the other laughed).  I looked up the term when I got home and it looks like, on the face of it, they are data pipelines.  They extract data, transform it, and load it for long term storage.  Many people use the outputs and they are reported to internal company managers and public agencies (municipal, state, federal).

So, are they data pipelines or are they too rudimentary to be classified such?  I ask, and the reason it's important to me is so I can speak of them in interviews as such.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Data-Pipelines" are generally hands-off and automatic. Are the processes you mentioned automated or manual?

Comment: They're "push-button".  The process is generally controlled by a button on an Access form or a process that's pre-written, but executed by a user in SAS.  It's not fully automatic, as invoices have to be placed in the correct folder, then the process is executed (for the Access ones).  For the SAS ones, I didn't have permission to save a SAS procedure on the SAS server, so that process is executed once a week to refresh and compress data.  The user is completely unaware of what it's doing, but it needs to be initiaizled by someone.

Comment: It's a rudimentary pipeline, but yes, a pipeline.  Usually the difference is thoughtful design versus just happened to do it a few times. You know when to consider dropping variables and creating look up tables instead or transforming your data to a normalized structure.

Comment: I would simply call it an ETL process.  The way it has been coded sounds like it can be automated and scheduled if so desired, or manually 'primed' for ad hoc situations once automated.

Comment: I agree with the above. At the bare minimum this is an ETL process. If you're taking data from multiple places and aggregating it into one analytic database designed for statistical procedures, reporting, etc., then it's at least an ETL process.